# WooCommerce - update product tax_class programmatically

Tags: woocommerce

I have an array like this:

```
$productArray = [[sku, vatPercent],[sku, vatPercent],...];
```

vatPercent values are 1 or 2.
I just only want to programmatically update woo-commerce products tax class with vatPercent values from the array like this:

```
if (!empty($productArray)):
    foreach ($productArray as $eachProduct):
        $product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($eachProduct['sku']);
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        $product->set_tax_status('taxable');
               
        if ( $eachProduct['vatPercent'] == 1 ) {
             $product->set_tax_class('tva19');
        }
        if ( $eachProduct['vatPercent'] == 2 ) {
             $product->set_tax_class('tva9');
        }
        $product->save();

    endforeach;
endif;
```

and nothing happens. No errors but no action either. What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Vic

Answer (score 0):

As I am checking your code and create the same scenario(generate $productArray with my product SKU) like this on my functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'init', 'woo_product_update_tax_class' );
function woo_product_update_tax_class(){
    $productArray = array(
        array(
            'sku' => 'SF1133569600-1',
            'vatPercent' => 1,
        ),
        array(
            'sku' => 'AB123456789',
            'vatPercent' => 2,
        ),
    );
    if (!empty($productArray)):
        foreach ($productArray as $eachProduct):
            // If you are using WooCommerce 2.3 version, you can call.
            $product_id = wc_get_product_id_by_sku($eachProduct['sku']);

            //echo  "<pre>"; print_r($product_id); exit;
            
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        
            $product->set_tax_status('taxable');
                    
            if ( $eachProduct['vatPercent'] == 1 ) {
                    $product->set_tax_class('tva19');
            }
            if ( $eachProduct['vatPercent'] == 2 ) {
                $product->set_tax_class('tva9');
            }
            $product->save();

    endforeach;
    endif;
}
```

It's working as expected, so if it's not working from your end, please check product_id(you are getting properly) by uncomment

```
//echo  "<pre>"; print_r($product_id); exit;
```

If you are not getting $product_id, please check your woocommerce version.

You can also get product_id from sku from other custom function like this:

```
 function get_product_by_sku( $sku ) {

   global $wpdb;

   $product_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key='_sku' AND meta_value='%s' LIMIT 1", $sku ) );

  // if ( $product_id ) 
  //    return new WC_Product( $product_id );

   if ( $product_id ) 
      return $product_id;

   return false;
}
```

You can also customize above function are return directly product information like commented above code(//return new WC_Product( $product_id );).